# How do I do an Left Outer Join in EF Core v3

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I have been trying to use the GroupJoin statement to do a left outer join on two tables so that i can get a list of rows in table A which does not have any items in table B.  However I keep getting an exception

```
  Exception found: Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<People>
      .GroupJoin(
          outer: DbSet<RiskGroup>,
          inner: person => (Nullable<int>)person.Id,
          outerKeySelector: risk => risk.AssessorId,
          innerKeySelector: (person, risks) => new {
              person = person,
              risks = risks
                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
           })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed.
```

which seems to imply that it is not possible in EF Core v3.  Does anyone know how to get around this problem or is my LINQ incorrect below:

```
    var Ids = destContext.People.GroupJoin(destContext.RiskGroup,
        person => person.Id,
        risk => risk.AssessorId,
        (person, risks) => new { person, risks = risks.DefaultIfEmpty() }).ToList();
```

I have trying to find all rows in the person table who doesn't have rows in the RiskGroup table.

Answer (score 6):

I have struggled with this myself and I would like to see if this help you

OK for starters, I am going to keep this simple.  Just find things are easier if we do
this is something that every developer comes across Company and address

the first table (Company) is the table that we could have multple records
the second table (Address) we have a single record for

```
         company => company.AddressId,
         address => address.AddressId,
```

So we are querying using the addressId of the address, I always used tableNameId, it makes things easier to read

So for the GroupJoin you now need output to be able to be used later in the query.

```
(company, address) = new (company, address)
```

And now you need a SelectMany - this is what screws everyone up
you need a record for when there is a null in Company

```
 s.address.DefaultIfEmpty(),
```

and the output from the SelectMany

```
 (s, address) => new { company = s.company, address });
```

Notice, very important - company must be s.company - not just company or the LEFT JOIN will not appear.

```
     var a = context.Companys.GroupJoin(context.Addresses,
             company => company.AddressId,
             address => address.AddressId,
             (company, address) => new { company, address })
             .SelectMany(s => s.address.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                        (s, address) => new { company = s.company, address });
    var outA = a.ToList();
```

for your specific issue

```
 var a = destContext.People.GroupJoin(destContext.RiskGroup,
             person => person.Id,
             risk => risk.AssessorId,
             (person, risk) => new { person, risk })
             .SelectMany(s => s.risk.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                        (s, risk) => new { person = s.person, risk })
             .Where(x => x.AssesorId == null);
        var outA = a.ToList();
```

Try that out and see if you get what you need